# Xcode constraints and uiimageview as a background

Tags: interface, storyboard, xcode6, constraints

I am sorry if I am going off topic, this is not a question about code, but I am having troubles with constraints

In my app I use a `UIImageView` as background, I set the constraint for the image to fit the screen and it works

But after that i have a lot of labels and buttons,and if i add even one constraint to one of these elements,it disappears or goes out of the `UIImage`

I want to set the `UIImageView` as background,so all the other elements can be placed on the image using constraints ,how do i do it?
To simplify the process can i group all of my interface elements in some views and then apply the constraints to the view?

I need a good explanation and/or tutorial about this elements, at the moment my interface on iPhone 4 fits ok until the iAd shows up, and on the other iPhones there is a lot of empty space

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this tutorial. Hopefully, it will works.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: thanks but i have already read that tutorial and doesn't fit to my case,i have an uiimage under all the other elementsm, in the tutorial he uses two different uiimage

Answer (score 0):

Try this: with one of you elements, cmd+click (or right-click) on it and drag upward until the background UIImage is highlighted.  Release and select 'left'.  This sets a pinning constraint to the left side of the background image.

Then cmd+click and drag to the side, and select 'top'.  This should pin your element to an intelligible spot; it may still need some sizing help, but at least you will be able to guess where it will show up.